# CSS3 column-fill horizontal overflow

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I implemented the following horizontally laid out lists.

list.html

```
<div class='options'>
  <div><input type='checkbox'><label>Check 01</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox'><label>Check 02</label></div>
  ...
</div>
```

style.css

```
.options {
  width: 345px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;

  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-width: 150px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;

  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I achieved the layout. However, when I tried to style the input elements with Google Add-ons stylesheet, the checkboxes are eclipsed as I scroll.

Here is the Google Add-ons stylesheet:
https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css

Not sure if it's relevant but the implementation was using Apps Script HTML service in IFRAME sandbox mode.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aj8wa6xf/

I know I made a mistake in the layout. Couldn't figure out what. Can someone please point out my mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a Chrome rendering bug. Works fine on Safari. Goes without saying this isn't even close to being widely supported by IE.

This is one of the notes of known issues with Chrome and multi-column layouts on **[caniuse.com]**[1](http://caniuse.com)

> - Chrome is reported to incorrectly calculate the container height, and    often breaks on margins, padding, and can display 1px of the
>     next    column at the bottom of the previous column.

Multi-column hasn't been adopted yet as part of any spec. It is a Release Candidate at best. Implementation in Browsers sometimes leads the specs and sometimes follows in  wake